# Grouping in MySQL by month and currency

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing all my sales in my webshops.
It looks something like this:

```
saletime            | saleprice  | fee  | currency
2014-01-01 00:51:27 | 89.00      | 6.9  | USD
2014-01-01 01:20:27 | 249.00     | 9.9  | SEK
2014-01-01 02:31:27 | 849.00     | 19.9 | SEK
```

I need to get total numbers, grouped by month and currency.

The result should look something like this:

```
Month   | Sum(saleprice) | Sum(fee) | Currency
01-2014 | 9829827.00     | 38738.00 | USD
01-2014 | 443827.00      | 738.00   | SEK
01-2014 | 439827.00      | 4738.00  | NOK

02-2014 | 9829827.00     | 38738.00 | USD
02-2014 | 443827.00      | 738.00   | SEK
02-2014 | 439827.00      | 4738.00  | NOK

03-2014 | 9829827.00     | 38738.00 | USD
03-2014 | 443827.00      | 738.00   | SEK
03-2014 | 439827.00      | 4738.00  | NOK
```

Without too much knowledge of advanced grouping myself I tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT SUM(saleprice), SUM(fee), currency 
FROM sales
GROUP BY (month(saletime), year(saletime)), currency
```

But I fail. How can this be solved?

Comment: You just need to make your year-month into a valid expression. For example `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%Y-%m"), currency`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by month + year, then currency:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%m-%Y") AS `Month`, SUM(saleprice), SUM(fee), currency
FROM sales
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%m-%Y"), currency
```

If you want to group all USD currency into one group and the rest into another:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%m-%Y") AS `Month`, SUM(saleprice), SUM(fee),
  IF(currency = 'USD', 'USD', 'Other') AS currency
FROM sales
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%m-%Y"), currency = 'USD'
```

Comment: thanks alot, exactly what I needed! :) if I can ask another thing, is it possible to group currencies so that "USD" will be in one group and all other currencies will be in a single merged group?

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(saletime,"%m-%Y"), IF(currency='USD','USD','other')`.

Answer (score 1):

You almos did it, try with :

```
SELECT sum(saleprice), sum(fee), currency 
FROM sales
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( creation_date, '%Y-%m'), currency
```